# Getting max x, max y, max z from feature points

Tags: c++

I have a `std::vector<Ogre::Vector3> featurePoints`. `Ogre::Vector3` has x, y, z `float` members.

I would like to get the max x, min x, max y, min y, max z and min z.

I have tried the following:

```
float maxX = std::max_element(featurePoints.begin(), featurePoints.end(),
                             [](Ogre::Vector3 a, Ogre::Vector3 b){return a.x < b.x;});
auto maxx = std::max_element(featurePoints.begin(), featurePoints.end(),
                             [](Ogre::Vector3 a, Ogre::Vector3 b){return a.x < b.x;});
auto maxy = std::max_element(featurePoints.begin(), featurePoints.end(),
                             [](Ogre::Vector3 a, Ogre::Vector3 b){return a.y < b.y;});
auto maxz = std::max_element(featurePoints.begin(), featurePoints.end(),
                             [](Ogre::Vector3 a, Ogre::Vector3 b){return a.z < b.z;});
auto minx = std::max_element(featurePoints.begin(), featurePoints.end(),
                             [](Ogre::Vector3 a, Ogre::Vector3 b){return a.x > b.x;});
auto miny = std::max_element(featurePoints.begin(), featurePoints.end(),
                             [](Ogre::Vector3 a, Ogre::Vector3 b){return a.y > b.y;});
auto minz = std::max_element(featurePoints.begin(), featurePoints.end(),
                             [](Ogre::Vector3 a, Ogre::Vector3 b){return a.z > b.z;});
```

Which gives this compiler error:

> No viable conversion from 'std::__1::__wrap_iter' to 'float'

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide detailed information about the error.

Comment: No viable conversion from 'std::__1::__wrap_iter<Ogre::Vector3 *>' to 'float'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `std::max_element` is an *iterator* to the element in a container, not an element itself. So the compiler issues a diagnostic when attempting to assign the result to a `float`.

But there's a better function: `std::minmax_element` which allows you to get the minimum and maximum values back in a single traversal:

```
auto pair = std::minmax_element(
    featurePoints.begin(),
    featurePoints.end(),
    [](Ogre::Vector3 a, Ogre::Vector3 b){return a.x < b.x;}
);
float minX = pair.first->x;
float maxX = pair.second->x;
```

Here, `pair` is a `std::pair` of two iterators, the first one is the iterator to the minimum, the second the iterator to the maximum.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element

Answer (score 1):

`std::max_element` returns an iterator to your container, so you can assign it then dereference to get an element

```
auto itMax = std::max_element(featurePoints.begin(), featurePoints.end(), [](Ogre::Vector3 a, Ogre::Vector3 b){return a.x < b.x;});
float maxX = itMax->x;
```

Or directly dereference

```
float maxX = std::max_element(featurePoints.begin(),
                              featurePoints.end(),
                              [](Ogre::Vector3 a, Ogre::Vector3 b){return a.x < b.x;})->x;
float minX = std::min_element(featurePoints.begin(),
                              featurePoints.end(),
                              [](Ogre::Vector3 a, Ogre::Vector3 b){return a.x < b.x;})->x;
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you look at my edit post, is it correct for calculating minx, miny,minz, maxx, maxy, maxz

Comment: You should use `max_element` and `min_element` appropriately, but both of them take a `<` comparison. Then as I mentioned in my answer you'll get iterators back, so you can dereference those to get whichever value you want back (`x`, `y`, or `z`)